# Bevel modifier doesn't change anything, even though in the tutorial it changes a lot

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I am following this tutorial from Ukramedia: [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8XSQhRcpfM)

He is adding a bevel modifier and it instantly looks better, when I do this however nothing seems to change. Here is how it looks **without** the bevel in the tutorial:
[image: No bevel]

Here is how it looks **with** bevel in the tutorial:
[image: With bevel]

However, in my project it always looks like the first picture. When using the bevel modifier blender says the verts are doubled in the bottom right, but it doesn't look like the second picture.

Project file: [Here](https://we.tl/t-slT3NGAFG1)

Comment: Hello :). Your mesh has lots and lots of double vertices, intersected faces and other problems. That's why the bevel modifier is confused.

Comment: I see, I have deleted a lot of vertices by merging them by distance and deleting loose, however its still not like it is in the tutorial :(

Comment: Well, the are many issues. I'd say remaking it from scratch would be faster than trying to repair it. To see all the problematic areas, uncheck *Clamp Overlap* in your Bevel modifier. That will force-bevel even the problematic parts.

Comment: Ah okay, its weird because I really thought I did everything correctly following the tutorial but I'll just start again. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Okay :). If you get stuck anywhere, feel free to ask a new question. Good luck.

Comment: I re did it and its working perfectly fine now, thank you!